# Trigger jenkins job by a specific dockerhub repository tag

Tags: jenkins, tags, dockerhub

I want to trigger jenkins job when a new Docker-image is builds in DockerHub in a specific tag.

The setup works fine with a default tag that is lastest.

Jenkins config:

Specified repositories will trigger this job:

```
mydockerhub/appname
```

However it doesn't work when I specify a tag like:

```
mydockerhub/appname:tags/testing
```

Can anyone let me know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for tagging a docker image is:

```
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

You cannot use a slash inside your tag. Use underscore or a dot instead.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: Thanks but I'm not gonna create a tag here. The tag has been already created and now I'm gonna set it in Jenkins job in order to be triggers when a new docker image is built with that tag in dockerhub/dockercloud.